# how to get datatable column names from json

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I have json file containing column names and data. I am able to populate datatable with data with hard coded column names in jsp. But I want to read column names too from json.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Below is the json file and my js code.

Json file

```
{
"aaData": [

    [
     "Name",
     "Description",
     "Date"
    ],
    [
        "Ronaldo",
        "Brazil",
        "1983"
    ],
    [
        "Rooney",
        "England",
        "1999"
    ]
]
```

}

js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#genericTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "resources/json/" + key + ".json"
    }).columnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
        aoColumns: [ { type: "text" },
                     { type: "text" },
                     null
                   ]
    }); 
});
```